# SwiftUI Can't Change the Master Pane Width iPad Landscape

Tags: xcode, swiftui, ipados

I have a SwiftUI app in full SwiftUI lifecycle that includes a basic Master/Detail style
of data presentation. For the iPad, I need a wider left (Master) pane and don't need the
Detail pane to be as wide as the default.

Apparently I'm not phrasing my searches well enough because I have not found any
articles that discuss this. I have tried setting a frame on the NavigationView, changing
the NavigationViewStyle and a few other wild shots but have not gotten anywhere.

Ideally, I'd like to code it so the user could adjust the width, but I'd settle for
simply being able to make it wider by default.

Here's the idea:

[image]

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 12.3 iOS/iPad 14.3